# Microsoft Azure Linux Diagnostic Extension issue

Tags: azure, diagnostic, extension

I have enabled LAD in azure Linux VM in ASM mode and have used below command:
`azure vm extension set ubuntuclassic LinuxDiagnostic Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics '3.0' --private-config-path private.json --public-config-path public.json.`
 I am not able to get metrics that I have mentioned in public.json file.

Extension is enabled, that I can check in Azure Portal.

Same configuration worked in ARM mode  and able to get custom metrics

Getting the following error:

`2017/06/08 09:10:29 ERROR:[Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.LinuxDiagnostic-3.0.107] Unknown exception occurred from generate_all_configs(). Msg: string index out of range

2017/06/08 09:10:29 ERROR:[Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.LinuxDiagnostic-3.0.107] Failed to perform extension operation Daemon with error:local variable 'config_invalid_reason' referenced before assignment, Traceback (most recent call last):`

Comment: Do you create your classic VM using Azure Market or using your custom images?

Comment: I have created vm using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: You could enable  Diagnostic  on Azure Portal, please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/vm-monitoring).

Comment: I have done that but to get custom metrics , like for filesystem / /mnt , /data . I have followed this document https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/diagnostic-extension and Iam getting error logs in extension.log file